# Simple Elevator Program Python Using While For Loop. Why does my loop not update every item on list?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

My below loop in python which goes through a list of customers seems to once it removes a customer from the list go back to the start of the while loop instead of repeating through for the rest of the customers. Can somebody please have a look at what I am doing wrong? Entire code is below and attached.

```
author = 'Alan Doonan'

import random
import time


class Building:                                                                                                                         # defines class building
    number_of_floors = 0                                                                                                                # sets number_of_floors variable to 0
    customer_list = []                                                                                                                  # creates an empty array for customer_list
    elevator = 0                                                                                                                        # sets elevator variable to 0

    def __init__(self, floors, customers):                                                                                              # initialize Building
        self.number_of_floors = floors                                                                                                  # assigns floors entered to number_of_floors
        for customerID in range(1, customers + 1):                                                                                      # assigns number of customers entered to customer_list in order
            new = Customer(customerID,self.number_of_floors)                                                                            # creates an instance called new of Customer class for number of customers entered in input
            self.customer_list.append(new)                                                                                              # appends new instance of customer to customer_list
        self.customer_list.sort(key = lambda x: x.current_floor)                                                                        # sorts customer_list by current_floor customer is on                                               # prints
        self.elevator = Elevator(floors,self.customer_list)                                                                             # creates instance of elevator with inputted floors and assigns customer_list to register_list                                                                            # prints
        self.run()                                                                                                                      # runs run method below

    def run(self):                                                                                                                      # method to operate the elevator
        print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++ELEVATOR IS NOW STARTING+++++++++++++++')                                                      # prints
        print('There are %d customers in the building' % (len(self.customer_list)))                                                     # prints
        number_of_customers = len(self.customer_list)                                                                                   # assigns current number of customers to number_of_customers variable
        self.output()                                                                                                                   # runs output method below

    def output(self):
        for customer in self.customer_list:                                                                                                   #prints lists of customers in building and their details
            print("Customer",customer.customerID,"is on floor",customer.current_floor,"and wants to go to",customer.destination_floor)

        #ELEVATOR MOVING UP LOOP
        while (self.elevator.current_floor < self.elevator.number_of_floors):
            self.elevator.current_floor +=1
            print('ELEVATOR MOVING UP')
            print(len(self.customer_list),'Customers in lift.')
            print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
            print('FLOOR',self.elevator.current_floor)

            for customer in self.customer_list:                                                                                             # Loop for each instance of Custumer in customer_list
                if (self.elevator.current_floor == customer.current_floor) & customer.customer_direction == 1:
                    customer.in_elevator = True
                    print('Customer',customer.customerID,'has entered the lift')
                if (self.elevator.current_floor == customer.destination_floor) & (customer.in_elevator == True) & customer.customer_direction ==1:
                    customer.in_elevator = False
                    self.customer_list.remove(customer)
                    print(customer.customerID,'has reached their destination')


        #ELEVATOR MOVING DOWN LOOP
        while (self.elevator.current_floor <= self.number_of_floors) & (self.elevator.current_floor > 1):
            self.elevator.current_floor -= 1
            print(len(self.customer_list),'Customers in lift.')
            print('ELEVATOR MOVING DOWN')
            print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
            print('FLOOR',self.elevator.current_floor)

            for customer in self.customer_list:
                if (customer.in_elevator == True):
                    customer.current_floor = self.elevator.current_floor
                if (self.elevator.current_floor == customer.destination_floor) & (customer.in_elevator == True) & (customer.customer_direction == -1):
                    customer.in_elevator = False
                    self.customer_list.remove(customer)
                    print('Customer',customer.customerID,'has reached their destination')

        print('There are',len(self.customer_list),'trapped in the elevator')                                                            #prints
        print('There are',len(Elevator.register_list),'people left on the register')
        print('Elevator run is done!!!')                                                                                                #prints

        print('CUSTOMERS STUCK IN LIFT ARE BELOW')
        for stuck in self.customer_list:
            print('Cust. ID:',stuck.customerID,'Dest. Floor:',stuck.destination_floor,'Curr. Floor:',stuck.current_floor,'In Elevator',stuck.in_elevator,'Direction',stuck.customer_direction)


class Elevator:
    number_of_floors = 0                                                                                                # the number of floors
    register_list = []                                                                                                  # the list of customers in the elevator
    current_floor = 0                                                                                                   # the current floor of the elevator
    up = 1                                                                                                              # moves the elevator up
    down = -1                                                                                                           # moves the elevator down

    def __init__(self, number_of_floors, register_list):
        self.number_of_floors = number_of_floors
        self.register_list = register_list

    def move(self):                                                                                                     # method to move the elevator by 1 floor
        pass;

    def register_customer(self, customers):                                                                             # customer goes into elevator
        for reg in customers:
            self.register_list.append(reg)



    def cancel_customer(self, customers):                                                                               # customer goes out of the elevator
        pass;


class Customer:
    current_floor = 0                                                                                                   # the current floor of the elevator
    destination_floor = 0                                                                                               # the destination floor of the elevator
    customerID = 0                                                                                                      # the customers ID
    in_elevator = False                                                                                                 # denotes whether customer is in the elevator
    finished = False                                                                                                    # denotes whether customer has reached the destination floor
    customer_direction = 0

    def __init__(self, customerID, floors):                                                                             # initilize Customer class
        self.customerID = customerID                                                                                    # assigns self.customerID to customerID
        self.current_floor = random.randint(1, floors)                                                                  # assigns self.current_floor to random int between 1 and floors entered
        self.destination_floor = random.randint(1, floors)                                                              # assigns seslf.destination_floor to random int between 1 and floors entered
        while self.destination_floor == self.current_floor:
            self.destination_floor = random.randint(1, floors)
        if self.current_floor < self.destination_floor:
            self.customer_direction = 1
        else:
            self.customer_direction = -1

def header():                                                                                                           # elevator animation at beginning of program
    print("                          ELEVATOR OPENING                        ")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++||+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++|       |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("++++++++++++++++|                             |+++++++++++++++++++")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("++++++|                                                 |+++++++++")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("                                                                  ")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("                          ELEVATOR CLOSING                        ")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("++++++|                                                 |+++++++++")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("++++++++++++++++|                             |+++++++++++++++++++")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++|       |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    time.sleep(.2)
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++||+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")


def main():                                                                                                             # main method
    try:                                                                                                                # try/except for user input menu
        floors = int(input('Enter the number of floors: '))                                                             # enter floors and assign to floors
        customers = int(input('Enter number of customers: '))                                                           # enter customers and assign to customers
        building = Building(floors, customers)  # instance of building created with inputs of floors and customers      # create instance of Building class (building)
    except ValueError:
        print('YOU DIDNT ENTER A NUMBER. START AGAIN.')
        main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # header()
    main()
```

[LINK TO FILE ON GITHUB](https://gist.github.com/alandoonan/f1e443468a40d363a969612a43f26475)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question without providing more scope. Please be more specific. Without a more exact question, I cannot say for sure-so please provide examples of input and output that lead you to believe this. However, if it looks like it is starting at the beginning of your while loop because it keeps printing out the same information, it may have to do with how you declared your classes; you have overloaded customerID as both a class variable and an instance variable. For more information see the docs. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects
Basically, I would get rid of the class variables inside customer that are also instance variables and then I would also refactor the sections below the comments #ELEVATOR MOVING UP LOOP and the going down loop to consolidate them, since you are reusing a lot of code needlessly here. Then refine the question that you are asking so that it is clearer